# How to fix Strapi Meilisearch Plugin?

Tags: strapi

Hooks in [strapi-plugin-meilisearch](https://github.com/meilisearch/strapi-plugin-meilisearch#-apply-hooks-) are not working. I did press `Reload Server` but it is not working. Hooks are not applying.

```
strapi: v3.6.2
strapi-plugin-meilisearch: v0.3.0
meilisearch: v0.20.0
```

Command used to start Strapi: `strapi dev`

[image: Hooks not working]

Comment: Hello! Which version of meilisearch are you using? Which version of strapi and of the plugin are you using? What command did you use to run strapi?

Comment: @Bidoubiwa Info added!

Comment: I found the bug! I'm fixing it :) I'll tell you when it is released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix has been released. Update the plugin `strapi-plugin-meilisearch` to v.0.3.1